# Deploying Keras model in Flask works locally, but not on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, flask, keras

I'm a student who's trying to create a Flask app that incorporates a Keras ML model. I've gotten the code to run locally, with `python app.py`, but when I push my code to Heroku, it spits out the following error:

```
2019-04-15T08:28:58.355650+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2019-04-15T08:28:58.355653+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
2019-04-15T08:28:58.355654+00:00 app[web.1]: response = self.full_dispatch_request()
2019-04-15T08:28:58.355656+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
2019-04-15T08:28:58.355658+00:00 app[web.1]: rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
2019-04-15T08:28:58.355660+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
2019-04-15T08:28:58.355661+00:00 app[web.1]: reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
2019-04-15T08:28:58.355663+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
2019-04-15T08:28:58.355665+00:00 app[web.1]: raise value
2019-04-15T08:28:58.355667+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
2019-04-15T08:28:58.355668+00:00 app[web.1]: rv = self.dispatch_request()
2019-04-15T08:28:58.355670+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
2019-04-15T08:28:58.355672+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
2019-04-15T08:28:58.355674+00:00 app[web.1]: File "app.py", line 62, in demo
2019-04-15T08:28:58.355675+00:00 app[web.1]: model = load_model('./model.h5')
2019-04-15T08:28:58.355677+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/saving.py", line 249, in load_model
2019-04-15T08:28:58.355678+00:00 app[web.1]: f = h5py.File(filepath, mode='r')
2019-04-15T08:28:58.355680+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/h5py/_hl/files.py", line 312, in __init__
2019-04-15T08:28:58.355682+00:00 app[web.1]: fid = make_fid(name, mode, userblock_size, fapl, swmr=swmr)
2019-04-15T08:28:58.355683+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/h5py/_hl/files.py", line 142, in make_fid
2019-04-15T08:28:58.355685+00:00 app[web.1]: fid = h5f.open(name, flags, fapl=fapl)
2019-04-15T08:28:58.355687+00:00 app[web.1]: File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
2019-04-15T08:28:58.355688+00:00 app[web.1]: File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
2019-04-15T08:28:58.355690+00:00 app[web.1]: File "h5py/h5f.pyx", line 78, in h5py.h5f.open
2019-04-15T08:28:58.355697+00:00 app[web.1]: OSError: Unable to open file (file signature not found)
```

My understanding is that the file for my Keras model, `model.h5`, isn't being loaded properly. Following some other Github issues and Stack Overflow answers, I've already verified that the git repository contains the file, and checked that the file isn't corrupt by downloading it from the repo and running it locally, but those don't seem to be the issues. I'd greatly appreciate it if anyone has any ideas on what's going on, and could point me in the right direction.

Here are a few of my other files for reference.

Procfile:

```
web: python app.py
```

requirements.txt:

```
gunicorn==19.9.0
requests==2.14.2
Flask==1.0.2
keras==2.2.2
numpy==1.15.2
pandas==0.23.4
Pillow==5.2.0
scipy==1.1.0
tensorflow==1.10.0
Werkzeug==0.14.1
h5py==2.8.0
```

And a snippet from my app.py:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```